# How can I display Notes & attachment in salesforce1 mobile

Tags: salesforce1-app, attachment, mobile, notes

I need to display notes and attachment in salesforce 1 in mobile view. please can any one help me out

Answer (score 3):

According to [Support for notes, documents, files and attachments in Salesforce1](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000206009), notes and attachments aren't supported in Salesforce1

> Salesforce1 supports documents that are uploaded through the Files action OR through Chatter. Documents and any attachments uploaded through the Notes and Attachments section on a record list view aren't guaranteed to be accessible in Salesforce1.  The content can still appear under the section, but Salesforce can't guarantee they will be viewable/downloadable in Salesforce1.